# Почему указывает ошибку на "<<"?

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Stack
{
private:
int maxSize, top;
string *array;

public:
Stack(int n)
{
    array = new string[n];
    maxSize = n;
    top = 0;
}

~Stack()
{
    delete [] array;
}

void pop(string a)
{
    if(top < maxSize) array[top++] = a;
    else
    {
        cout << "Stack is FULL!";
    }
}

string push()
{
    if(top != 0) return array[--top];
    else
    {
        cout << "Stack is EMPTY!";
    }
}

void print()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < top; i++)
    cout << array[i] << " "; // Почему тут в "<<" после cout указывается красным?
    cout << endl;
}
};

 int main()
{
string str;
Stack N1(10);

N1.pop(str);
N1.print();

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
 }
```

Выводится ошибка: no operator "<<" matches these operands operand types are: std::ostream << std::string. Как исправить?

Comment: array это ключевое слово, замените на что нибудь другое. Это верно для компилятора microsoft.

Comment: Заменил. Но проблема все та же @igumnov

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!

Answer (score 1):

1) array это ключевое слово из пространства имен cli, замените на что нибудь другое. Это верно для компилятора Microsoft.

2)Теперь осталось заменить

```
#include <string.h> 
//на
#include <string>
```

Вуаля. Бинго. Profit 1111!!!!.

Очередной кривой, велосипедный копи-паст стэк отправляется покорять систему.

Лучше используйте вместо своего творения шаблон std::stack.

Comment: >array это ключевое слово из пространства имен cli, замените на что нибудь другое. Это верно для компилятора Microsoft.

 Если `C++\CLI` не включать, то это не будет ключевым словом, хоть и будет всё равно подсвечиваться. И кстати, как ключевое слово может быть "из пространства имён"? Ключевые слова всегда самые глобальные, и их нельзя ничем переопределить.

Comment: Это контекстно чувствительное слово. Как вы правильно заметили оно подсвечивается синим даже если флаг отключен, поэтому я посоветовал его переименовать. Называть объект класса словом "array" это реально плохая идея. Пространство имен cli нужно для устранения конфликтов между С++ и С++ CLR кодом. Ключевое слово можно легко переопределить препроцессором, правда так вы конечно не сможете поменять ассемблерный код который генерирует компилятор при его прочтении.

Comment: @igumnov, я подозреваю что это ему в институте задали)